# PHP - Count XML Child Nodes

Tags: php, xml

I have XML that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apiresponse>
  <response>
    <services>
      <service>
        <Carrier>Carrier1</Carrier>
      </service>
      <service>
        <Carrier>Carrier2</Carrier>
      </service>
      <service>
        <Carrier>Carrier3</Carrier>
      </service>
      <service>
        <Carrier>Carrier4</Carrier>
      </service>
    </services>
  </response>
</apiresponse>
```

This is stored inside the variable **$result**.

I want to count the number of nodes within **services**.  How do I go about this when the services node doesn't have a name or ID?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
echo count($xml->services);
```

Thanks!

Comment: there is no `<services>` at the top of your xml. it'd be `$xml->response->services`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use this:

```
echo $xml->response->services->service->count();
```

or you use a loop:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

foreach ($xml as $services) {
    foreach($services as $service) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($service->count());
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great! If I wanted to loop through each service and grab the Carrier value, how would I edit your loop? I can't quite get my head round it - Thanks!

Comment: another foreach to loop the services:

`foreach ($xml as $services) {
    foreach($services as $service) {
        foreach($service as $carrier) {
            echo $carrier->Carrier . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}`